# How to find user information using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I want to find user `id` and `Email` from mysql query

I have three table in mysql database

1. users 2. photographer_timetables 3.jobs

1.users

[image: user table]

2.photographer_timetables 
[image: photographer timetable]

3 jobs
[image]

here is my query

```
   SELECT Users.id AS `Users__id`
      , Users.email AS `Users__email` 
   FROM users          Users 
   LEFT 
   JOIN photographer_timetables pt    
     ON (pt.user_id = users.id AND role =3) 
  RIGHT JOIN jobs jb 
     ON (jb.photographer_id = pt.user_id 
     AND HOUR(jb.job_time) !='12:00:00'  
     AND jb.job_date !='2016-03-21')    
 WHERE (HOUR(start_time) <= '08:00:00'  
    AND weekday = 1)
```

I want to find those users information who is not available in `job_date` and `job_time`

my sql query return blank but o/p should be at least on row

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements, and a desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`.

**Query**

```
select * from users
where not exists (
  select 1 from jobs
  where jobs.user_id = users.id
);
```

Hope that once the job over, you are deleting the row from `jobs` table.

And if you want to check who all are available for a particular date. Then

**Query**

```
select * from users
where not exists (
  select 1 from jobs
  where jobs.user_id = users.id
  and jobs.job_date = '2016-03-23' -- change the date accordingly
);
```